# execution order for cout in C++

Tags: c++

## c++

When printing to console, if function execution is sequential it would seem logical the ordered array would be printed after calling insertionSort, however order list does not print until next loop. Any help would be appreciated.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

void insertionSort(int* array, int size) {
    
    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
        
        int key = i - 1;

        while (i > 0 && array[key] > array[i] ) {

            int tmp = array[i];
            array[i] = array[key];
            array[key] = tmp;

            i -= 1;
            key -= 1;
        }

    }

}

const int ARRAY_MAXSIZE = 5;

int main(void) {

    int *array = (int*)calloc(ARRAY_MAXSIZE, sizeof(int));
    int input;

    cout << "Enter 5 digits\n";
    
    for (int size=0; size < ARRAY_MAXSIZE; size++) {

        cout << size << " index ";
        
        cin >> input;
        array[size] = input;
    
        insertionSort(array, size);
        
        for (int j=0; j <= size; j++) {

            cout << array[j];
        }
        cout << '\n';
    }

}
```

[Console Entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLtuA.png)

Comment: Was it your intention to call `insertionSort` while you are inputting values?  I would expect `insertionSort` to be called *after* all of the values are inputted.

Comment: Think about what value `size` has when you call `insertionSort`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic off-by-one error. Your `insertionSort` expects you to pass the number of elements to sort via the parameter `size`. But your main loop is always holding a value that is one less than the size immediately after adding an element.

I want to say that bugs like this are easily discovered by stepping through your program's execution with a debugger. If you don't know how to use a debugger, start learning *now*. It is one of the most important tools used by developers.

Anyway, the quick fix is to change your function call to:

```
insertionSort(array, size + 1);
```

However, as Paul McKenzie pointed out in comments, it's a bit crazy to do this every time you add a new element because your function sorts an entire unsorted array. Your array is always *nearly* sorted except for the last element. You only need to call that function once after your input loop is done:

```
// Read unsorted data
for (int size = 0; size < ARRAY_MAXSIZE; size++) {
    cout << size << " index ";
    cin >> input;
    array[size] = input;
}    

// Sort everything
insertionSort(array, ARRAY_MAXSIZE);
    
// Output
for (int j = 0; j < ARRAY_MAXSIZE; j++) {
    cout << array[j];
}
cout << '\n';
```

But if you want every insertion to result in a sorted array, you can "slide" each new value into place after inserting it. It's similar to a single iteration of your insertion-sort:

```
// Sort the last element into the correct position
for (int i = size; i >= 1 && array[i] > array[i - 1]; i--)
{
    std::swap(array[i], array[i - 1]);
}
```

Even better, you don't need to swap all those values. You simply read the value, then shuffle the array contents over to make room, then stick it in the right spot:

```
// Read next value
cin >> input;

// Shuffle elements to make room for new value
int newPos = size;
while (newPos > 0 && array[newPos - 1] > input) {
    array[newPos] - array[newPos - 1];
    newPos--;
}

// Add the new value
array[newPos] = input;
```